# Display the line between the Header and first data line in winform Listview

Tags: c#, winforms

I am a newer,in VisualStudio,I am make a C# winform program.
I want make a listview.I have set the gridlines=true.
But between the Header and the first data line,there is no gridline.

How can I show it?

[image]

Comment: I find `ListView` to be horrible to work with, and it has a number of deficiencies (such as not drawing a line under the header and the vertical lines of the header not lining up with the vertical lines of the other rows). Have you considered using [`DataGridView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) instead?

Comment: This is how system draws it. You can't do anything about it except set the `OwnerDraw` property to `true` and handle `DrawItem` and `DrawColumnHeader` events. Even then it will be a workaround, not actual solution. Further more, try to change back color of your list view, Item and column header.

Comment: Yes, now I change to datagridview.It works fine.Thanks for your help.